# What this phrase "Try to make you architecture more horizontal rather than vertical" means?

Tags: php, performance, architecture

I've just listened to http://www.zend.com/webinar/PHP/70170000000bAuS-webinar-php-performance-principles-and-tools-20100218.flv (Zend webinar about PHP performance).

I can't understand what this phrase means "Try to make you architecture more horizontal rather than vertical" (see screenshot)

[alt text http://img2.pict.com/4e/4d/18/3358007/0/screenshot2b153.png](http://img2.pict.com/4e/4d/18/3358007/0/screenshot2b153.png)

Thank you.

Comment: A fantastic resource for scalability discussions and insights into some pretty exotic solutions http://highscalability.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple example of horizontal scaling VS. vertical scaling just with Database's

Given an example application like so:
Application has many clients, each client has multiple users.

update:
No client needs to know about another client, each user belongs exclusively to one client

## Vertical scaling:

Client data is stored in a normalized SQL based database.
user credentials for all users is stored in client_users table.

### Benefits

1. Shortest path of resistance for development
2. relatively easy to maintain integrity with
3. Easy to backup

### Problem:

Because all client credentials are stored in this one table along with related data, to maintain or increase performance would require beefing up your database tier with more resources or investing in more slaves to this one master.

## Horizontal scaling:

Each client exists on a prefixed table schema.  client_users becomes client01_users

### Benefits

Someone with intermediate level skills in DB administration could write a simple script to copy client#_* tables to a new DB server in about 5 minutes ( then another hour to sanity check/test/verify).  In this way you can push your low traffic clients onto a overbooked server and profit from the infrastructure savings while charging your higher traffic clients for requiring dedicated hardware.

### Problems

1. Maintenance/development time can extend into oblivion and paralyse development entirely if shared nothing techniques don't include automation and schema change management systems.
2. A simple task like adding/dropping a column will take much longer to peform as you have to do it on multiple tables/machines in lockstep to software changes.
3. Backup's get pretty interesting sometimes

## Summary

If in the beginning I can see an opportunity for shared nothing, I will fight tooth and nail to get that implemented.  For new client's with scaling issues, after contracted my initial proposal will include refactoring to incorporate sharding or shared nothing principals.  In my mind, the extra complexity can be managed if approached/handled correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Netlog is doing horizontal scaling ( see slides http://www.slideshare.net/folke/netlog-what-we-learned-about-scalability-high-availability-430211 ). But I think it is really difficult to make horizontal scaling for databases because sometimes you need to join tables from different databases and you can solve this problem only with multiple small (but fast) selects.

Comment: I agree it can be difficult, but I don't follow what you're trying to say.

Comment: Let's imagine that we store users 1-1000 in db#1 and 1001-2000 in db#2. user_id = 5 have friendship with user_id = 5, user_id=1005 and user_id=1006. There are some difficulties of getting detailed list of friends for user_id=5. But I don't think that projects using horizontal scaling are storing such information (friendship relations) in database. This is an artifical problem. PS: Sorry for my english.

Comment: No problem I was raised speaking/writing English yet it's mastery has alluded me as well.
As for the problem you mention, that might be a problem better handled by a map-reduce based data store.

Answer (score 1):

Horizontal scalability represents the ease you have to add more servers to your architecture.

Vertical scalability represents adding more ressources to a single server (as in more CPU, RAM ...).

Comment: Ho do I apply it to PHP? For example, I have 1 good server which serves whole PHP application (current avg. load is ~2.5-3.5). Application is optimized; there is no includes, just a single big (~3Mb) php file. Database, memcache & redis are on another servers. What can I do with application server? Should I buy more powerful server or should I buy two more servers and execute php through fast-cgi?